# Yosemite - Finder has a disconnect button when attached to OSX Server, not working

Tags: finder, macos, osx-server

You can endlessly click disconnect, but you are never disconnected.  On the OSX Server (Yosemite Server.app 4.0.2), you can see your user account still connected, on the client (Yosemite 10.10.1) the finder still shows the folders and the disconnect button.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the Finder, select the "Go" menu > "Connect to Server...", then click on the Recent Servers menu button (button with tiny clock, to the right of the "+" button) and select "Clear Recent Servers".

Now go to a Finder window, select the server from the list and click on the Disconnect button and the server will be disconnected.

(OS 10.10.3)

Comment: 10.10.3 here, doesn't work :(

Answer (score -1):

I can shake off the hung connection on 10.10.5 by rebooting the Mac and on Yosemite it takes so long that it requires going to stick the kettle on!

- `sudo killall Finder` doesn't sort it for me.
- I wrote an Applescript to force refresh all Finder windows — doesn't sort it.
- Cleared recent servers and hit disconnect — eventually worked if I left it alone for 10 minutes. It's marginally quicker to reboot the Mac (allowing for the slooooowwwwww process of quitting all running apps, especially if any of them are Adobe fodder).